# Discord бот не отвечает на новые команды

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Бот работает и отвечает на старые команды а вот на новые никак не хочет отвечать.В настройках Privileged Gateway Intents все галочки стоят и все разрешения выданы
intents.message_content = True если даже убрать тоже не помогает код и без него работает
[image: фотка почему то не вставляется]

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from steam import Steam
from decouple import config

# Получаем ключ API Steam и токен Discord из переменных среды или файла .env
KEY = config("STEAM_API_KEY")
TOKEN = config("Discord_API_TOKEN")

# Инициализируем клиент API Steam
steam = Steam(KEY)

# Определяем app ID для Squad (ID игры в Steam)
squad_app_id = 393380

# Настраиваем намерения Discord для доступа к содержимому сообщений
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True

# Создаем клиент Discord
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# Определяем дерево команд
tree = discord.app_commands.CommandTree(client)

# Словарь для хранения привязок Steam ID к Discord ID
bindings = {}

# Функция для проверки валидности Steam ID
def check_steamid(steam_id):
    if len(steam_id) == 17 and steam_id.isdigit():
        return True
    return False

# Функция для получения времени игры в Squad
def get_playtime(games, squad_app_id):
    for game in games:
        if game.get('appid') == squad_app_id:
            return game.get('playtime_forever', None)
    return None

# Обработчик события, когда бот готов и подключен к Discord
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот Discord запущен.")

# Slash-команда для отображения статистики Squad
@tree.command(name="squadstats", description="Время игры в Squad")
async def squad_command(interaction):
    # Запрашиваем Steam ID пользователя
    await interaction.response.send_message("Введите ваш Steam ID:")

    # Определяем функцию проверки для фильтрации сообщений от одного и того же пользователя
    def check(m):
        return m.author == interaction.user and m.channel == interaction.channel

    # Ожидаем от пользователя отправки его Steam ID
    steam_id = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    # Проверка валидности Steam ID
    if not check_steamid(steam_id.content):
        await interaction.followup.send("Неверный Steam ID. Пожалуйста, введите 17-значный цифровой код.")
        return

    # Получаем список игр пользователя из Steam
    try:
        user_games = steam.users.get_owned_games(steam_id.content)
    except Exception as e:
        await interaction.followup.send(f"Ошибка: {e}")
        return

    # Извлекаем список игр
    try:
        games = user_games['games']
    except KeyError:
        await interaction.followup.send("В настройках конфиденциальности откройте доступ к вашим играм.")
        return

    # Ищем Squad в списке игр
    playtime_forever = get_playtime(games, squad_app_id)

    # Выводим результат
    if playtime_forever is not None:
        playtime_hours = round(playtime_forever / 60, 1)
        await interaction.followup.send(f"Время игры в Squad: {playtime_hours:.1f} часов")
    else:
        await interaction.followup.send("Игра Squad не найдена в списке игр пользователя.")

# Slash-команда для привязки Steam ID
@tree.command(name="bindsteamid", description="Привязывает ваш Steam ID к профилю")
async def bind_command(interaction):
    # Запрашиваем Steam ID пользователя
    await interaction.response.send_message("Введите ваш Steam ID:")

    # Проверяем, был ли уже привязан Steam ID к этому пользователю
    if interaction.author.id in bindings:
        await interaction.send("Ваш Steam ID уже привязан к профилю.")
        return

    # Определяем функцию проверки для фильтрации сообщений от одного и того же пользователя
    def check(m):
        return m.author == interaction.user and m.channel == interaction.channel

    # Ожидаем от пользователя отправки его Steam ID
    steam_id = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

@tree.command(name="unbindsteamid", description="Отвязывает ваш Steam ID от профиля")
async def unbind_command(interaction):
    # Проверяем, был ли привязан Steam ID к этому пользователю
    if interaction.author.id not in bindings:
        await interaction.send("Ваш Steam ID не привязан к профилю.")
        return

    # Удаляем Steam ID из словаря
    del bindings[interaction.author.id]

    # Отправляем сообщение о successful unbind
    await interaction.send("Ваш Steam ID успешно отвязан от профиля.")

@tree.command(name="ded", description="description")
async def slash_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):    
    await interaction.response.send_message("command")
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: > Бот работает и отвечает на старые команды а вот на новые никак не хочет отвечать.
Не слишком понимаю значение этой строчки

Comment: раньше была только одна команда /squadstats и она работает без проблем а после добавления новых 3-х команд bindsteamid,unbindsteamid и ded не работают хотя код вроде правильный, бот запускается и работает и никаких ошибок в логах не выдает а прикол еще в том что если я заменю код внутри /squadstats допустим нам bindsteamid то код сработает и все правильно выведется

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось нужно было в настройках сервера выдать боту все нужные разрешения хотя это уже было сделано когда бот добавлялся на сервер